# Loop through navigation menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, menu, navigation, items

relative(?) links:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

hello

i got this navigation menu

```
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><div id="menuItem1" class="menuItem"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">PORTFOLIO</a></div></td>
        <td><div id="menuItem2" class="menuItem">ABOUT ME</div></td>
        <td><div id="menuItem3" class="menuItem">CONTACT</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><div id="selectA1" class="selectA current"></div></td>
        <td><div id="selectA2" class="selectA"></div></td>
        <td><div id="selectA3" class="selectA"></div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

the selectA class is a rectangle that will select the menuItem when your mouse moves over it

the long code would be like

```
$("#menuItem1").mouseover(function () {
    $("#selectA1").stop().animate({opacity: 1},{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
});

$("#menuItem2").mouseover(function () {
    $("#selectA2").stop().animate({opacity: 1},{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
});

$("#menuItem3").mouseover(function () {
    $("#selectA3").stop().animate({opacity: 1},{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
});

$("#menuItem1").mouseout(function () {
    $("#selectA1").stop().animate({opacity: 0},{ queue: false, duration: 400 });
});

$("#menuItem2").mouseout(function () {
    $("#selectA2").stop().animate({opacity: 0},{ queue: false, duration: 400 });
});

$("#menuItem3").mouseout(function () {
    $("#selectA3").stop().animate({opacity: 0},{ queue: false, duration: 400 });
});
```

but i thought it could be shorter if i'd loop over those

so i tried to loop through those menuItems so that the rectangle will appear for all menu items

what i tried in javascript, all didnt work

```
var i=1;
for (i=1;i<=3;i++) {
$("#menuItem"+i).mouseover(function () {
    $("#selectA"+i).stop().animate({opacity: 1},{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
});
}
```

and

```
var i=1;
while (i<=3) {
$("#menuItem"+i).mouseover(function () {
    $("#selectA"+i).stop().animate({opacity: 1},{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
});
```

and

```
$(".selectA").each(function (i) {
$("#menuItem"+i).mouseover(function () {
    $("#selectA"+i).stop().animate({opacity: 1},{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
});
}


i++;
}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you would be better off with [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) rather than a [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)/[`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) pair.

Secondly, you don't need to use `each` at all, there is a nice simple relationship between your `.menuItem` and `.selectA` elements: they have the same suffix number in their `id` attributes. So, you could do the whole thing with something simple like this:

```
$('.menuItem').hover(
    function() {
        var n = this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
        $('#selectA' + n).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 },{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
    },
    function() {
        var n = this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
        $('#selectA' + n).stop().animate({ opacity: 0 },{ queue: false, duration: 200 });
    }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eza8b/

As far as why this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $("#menuItem" + i).mouseover(function () {
        $("#selectA" + i).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 200 });
    });
}
```

doesn't work goes, you're having a classic closure problem. The functions that you supply to `.mouseover` are closures over `i` so all of them end up using the last value that `i` had and that value is 4; that means that all of the inner selectors end up as `$('selectA4')` and that doesn't refer to anything useful. If you really want to use a loop then you can force `i` to be evaluated when you want it to be with this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    (function(n) {
        $("#menuItem" + n).mouseover(function () {
            $("#selectA" + n).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 200 });
        });
    })(i);
```

or this:

```
function build_animator(i) {
    return function() {
        $('#selectA' + i).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 200 });
    };
}
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    $("#menuItem" + i).mouseover(build_animator(i));
```

Comment: thank you, do you have a link to a page where i can learn about this part of the code: this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
i will google it anyway :)

Comment: @Mellroy: Have a look at the MDN page for replace (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), the MDN JavaScript reference is pretty good in general (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) and certainly better than w3schools (who have no relation at all to the real W3).

Comment: thank you for the link, and explanation of what i did wrong. very usefull!